# How can i convert these .json IDs to id numbers?

Tags: json

the server is currently down and i want to figure out what id number it was up to, they should be sequential with the first one the last id. thanks

```
"_id" : "580de2327c04b5177742dd8b",  -- largest
"_id" : "580de0f87c04b5177742dcea",
"_id" : "580de0c27c04b5177742dcde",
"_id" : "580de0097c04b5177742dcb1",
"_id" : "580ddd337c04b5177742dbf6",
```

Comment: So pull out the last one, if they are sequential, then the last one will always be the largest.

Comment: @MarcB It appears that they are in reverse sequence, so it would be the first one, not the last.

Comment: You say "they should be sequential with the first one the last id". Do you mean *should be" or "are"? This is very important.

Comment: trueyeah, they are decreasing, so... first one.

Comment: yea sorry, the first number is the largest id, can these be converted to a decimal id number or formula to show what the next id would have been?

Comment: What database are you using? Looks like mongo but I'm not sure.

Comment: yea it's mongo. thanks.